# How to find what user is logged into a computer in Active Directory? Windows Server 2022

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is there a way in Active Directory to query a Computer object to find the last user who logged in? I have a couple of computers that are not active and I would like to locate them or username know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could query the event log and filter for the machine names.

The events are kept per-DC, so in a multi DC setup you will have to grep trough every DCs logs. Check your retention policy, so that you don't miss events which are over your size/date limit.